# iPhone Fluid Stream Coding

Tags: iphone, physics, game-physics, fluid

My Programmer is having a hard time getting the physics to work for fluid simulation in an iPhone game. Basically, he needs to get a drop of water to continually flow down the screen and maintain a trail behind it. He can't get that exact "fluid" look to it. Any suggestions? Example code? or any help? :)

Thanks!

Comment: What parts has he solved already? A static droplet? A still shot of a drop with a trail?

Answer (score 0):

it realy depends on how much prosess you want to spend for this simulation, one of hte easies ways to do so is to simulate your drop using springs, just put 5 or 6 nodes and connect them to each other using springs, (you have to play with the number of springs to get the best result) and then you just have to overly your nodes to draw your drop, heres the sample code( though in CPP) to create springs and move them

```
Node nodes[6];
Spring springs[36];

int t = 0;

for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    for(int j=i+1;j<6;j++,t++)
        spring[t].initialize(node + i,node + j);

while(true)
{
    for(int i=0;i<36;i++)
        springs[i].update();
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        node [i].update();
    drawstuff(nodes);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a bunch for the help :)! Ill go ahead and try this out and if it doesnt work hopefully I can find an Engine